# Run AT commands from adb shell on Redmi 7

Tags: linux, gsm, at-command, adb

I tried this:

```
echo -e "ATD123456789;\r" > /dev/smd0
```

and then when I ran:

```
cat /dev/smd0
```

I got this output:

```
ATD123456789;
```

Is that what I'm supposed to see? The phone didn't respond to the command.

Update: The phone made a call when I used smd7 or smd11. The problem is I'm trying to send SMS messages using AT+CMGS and it's not working.

Update2: I run this command:`cat /dev/smd7 & echo -e "AT+CMGS=24;\r" > /dev/smd7`.
Then I enter the PDU message and I get this: `/system/bin/sh: 079...771B: not found`

Comment: Would you mind if I added the linux tag? I see you are using Android, but it is applicable to linux too.

Comment: No, of course. I added it, thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your +CMGS issue? You can ask here in comments, and I'll help if I can. Anyway if it is not a duplicate it is better to ask a different question.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate, I didn't find a specific question about Redmi 7 with the problems I have. It worked great a few minutes ago, now again it's not working, I don't know why. Please see my comments in the accepted answer below.

Comment: since some genius deleted my answer, here it is: ``strace 2>/dev/null -e inject=ioctl:retval=0 microcom /dev/smdXX``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, the command

```
ATD<number>;\r
```

performs a **voice call** to the destination number `<number>` (without the semicolon `;` the call type would depend o the current settings of `AT+FCLASS` command).

By default the `OK` result code would be received as soon as it starts remotely ringing, so after some seconds. But it would take even more if there are network problems or the remote number is unavailable/doesn't exist.

The default timeout of `ATD` command during a voice call is 30s, and can be changed by issuing `ATS7` command. For example, to set a 1 minute timeout:

```
ATS7=60
```

---

The answer you get is the **command echo**: in fact the modem, by default, echoes every character sent to its AT port (the echo can be desabled through `ATE0` command and aenabled again with `ATE1`). Receiving it **is the proof that the modem is correctly powered on and that it communicates correctly.

So, even though I'm aware that's not the only thing you expect to seee (you would like to see an answer!) you are actually supposed to see it.

---

Some pieces of advice in order to receive your answer:

1. Start providing simplier commands with shorter timeouts. For example the very basic `AT`.
2. Make sure to wait at least the maximum command timeout
3. Set the `cat` command in background and before starting providing commands:

```
    cat /dev/smd0 &

    echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0
    OK
```

Note: I'm not aware of any timeout in [cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) command.

Comment: I ran this command: <cat /dev/smd0 & echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0> and I got this: <[1] 17145
onc:/ # AT>  and then if I hit Enter I get this: <[1] + Done                 \cat /dev/smd0>. Everything is without the '<' and '>'.

Comment: It looks like it works now, thanks! onc:/ # cat /dev/smd7 & echo -e "AT+CMGF=?;\r" > /dev/smd7
output:
[2] 18311
onc:/ # AT+CMGF=?;
+CMGF: (0-1)

OK

Comment: Now again I get "AT+CMGF=?;" as output instead of "OK". What could have changed?

Comment: I have this on my shell: <127|onc:/ #>. It was 130, and after I ran Ctrl+Z it changed to 127. When the commands worked I had no number at all. What are these numbers?

Comment: Now I don't have a number in the beginning of the line but it's still not working..

Comment: I restarted my phone, it still didn't work. I ran <echo -e "ATD123456789;\r" > /dev/smd0>, and only then I got OK response and now the other commands are working again...

Comment: @RonyTesler make sure to wait for network registration (10-13secs)

Comment: I run <cat /dev/smd7 & echo -e "AT+CSCS="GSM";\r" > /dev/smd7> and I get ERROR. when I run <cat /dev/smd7 & echo -e "AT+CSCS=?;\r" > /dev/smd7> I get <+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")>. Any ideas?

Comment: @RonyTesler That's because you cannot send double quotes (`"`) through echo, because that character is used to enclose the data to be sent. If you want to send such characters you have to escape them with `\`: something like `"AT+CSCS=\"GSM\";\r"`

Comment: This worked: <cat /dev/smd7 & echo "AT+CSCS=\"GSM\";\r" > /dev/smd7>.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the "-e" in "echo -e" should do it..

Answer (score 0):

To have an interactive session you can use:
`strace 2>/dev/null -e inject=ioctl:retval=0 microcom /dev/smdXX`

Without the strace command, microcom returns an ioctl error.
Strace makes microcom think the ioctl succeeded and so it allows it to continue and run.